# python doubly linked list - insertAfter node

Tags: python, iterator, nodes, doubly-linked-list

Im creating a python class to implement a doubly linked list. I have a seperate class for the DLL node itself and a class for the list.
This is my class for the DLL nodes:
    class DLLNode:

```
def __init__(self,element,nextnode=None,prevnode=None,):

    self._element = element
    self._next = nextnode
    self._prev = prevnode
```

I have a method called `insertAfter(self,x,y)` which inserts node y after the first occurence x. Which is this :

```
if self.size != 0:
        n = DLLNode(y)
        if self.head._element == x:
            n._next = self.head._next
            self.head._next._prev = n
            n._prev = self.head
            self.head._next = n
            self.size += 1

        elif self.tail._element == x:
            self.tail._next = n
            n._prev = self.tail
            n._next = None
            self.tail = n
            self.size += 1
        else:
            iterator = self.head._next
            while iterator._next is not None:
                if iterator._element == x:
                    n._next = iterator._next
                    iterator._next._prev = n
                    n._prev = iterator
                    iterator._next = n
                    self.size += 1
                else:
                    iterator = iterator._next
```

when i run this function however, the function loops forever, when i kill the function myself, the error refers back to the 4th last line  `iterator._next = n` it doesnt say anything else which is why im confused. 
Would greatly appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop

```
while iterator._next is not None:
```

in `then` branch you doesn't change `iterator` value. On every iteration both conditions `iterator._next is not None` (from while loop) and `if iterator._element == x:` are `True` (because `iterator` contain same value). And you get infinity loop. Try to add `break` at the end of `then` branch.